# Apache Spark distrbuted Algorithms explanation

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce

I am confused about the implementation of the MLlib in Spark. How are the algorithms deployed on a distributed enviroment like HDFS?

I am not able to find any white papers about the algorithm implemenation.

Is there a diffrence between the implementation of ML Algorithms with Map Reduce? 
I am happy about any help (Links, Documentation, Papers,comments)

Have a nice day.

Comment: I won't downvote but this question is way off topic / too broad. And if you're really interested learn some Spark basics and check the source of the algorithm of interest. You won't find  a better way.

Comment: I am familiar with the basic concepts of ML algorithms like decision tress, svm's etc. But on a distributed enviroment where my data for the training of the model in spread over a lot of nodes there musst be some changes on the basic algoithm concept. For Map Redouce i found information about the new implementation (For example C4.5 http://www.sersc.org/journals/IJDTA/vol7_no1/5.pdf ). But i dont find something about the implementation difference to apache spark.

Comment: Spark doesn't implement C4.5. But fundamentally there a few dozens of algorithms in MLlib solving different classes of problems. There is no single strategy and typically you don't use the same algorithms that you use for single threaded or even local parallel processing. Many problems can be reduced to some type of optimization and solved using some variant of GD or BFGS algorithms. Other may use some Spark specific solutions.

Comment: Do you have any futher information on the Spark MLlib implemented Decision Tree? I am currently working on my bachelor degree and i want do dig more in this direction for my thesis. I am not looking in an implementation guid for spark. I am more focused on the algorithm behind. But anyway thank you for your time :)

Comment: https://spark-summit.org/2014/scalable-distributed-decision-trees-in-spark-mllib/ and https://databricks.com/blog/2014/09/29/scalable-decision-trees-in-mllib.html